# Why is chrome requesting /CACHE when i have manifest='cache-manifest'

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

```
<html manifest="/cache.manifest" class="ui-mobile landscape min-width-320px min-width-480px min-width-768px min-width-1024px">
```

From the chrome console:

```
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (404) http://example.com/CACHE
```

From the rails logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/CACHE"):
```

Am I missing something? I guess I should just rename cache.manifest to CACHE or what? Could it be something with jquerymobile?

Comment: ok my miss, I had an invalid cache file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had missed the colon in the cache manifest file

```
CACHE
```

the new version

```
CACHE:
```